# MYSQL trigger returning null error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a mysql trigger using MAMP for a joomla2.5 application.
My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `getDivision` BEFORE INSERT ON `encex_autoschedGames`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

select division into @div_a from encex_autoschedTeams where team_name = new.team_a; 
set new.division = @div_a;

END
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Column 'division' cannot be null
```

The story:

I have two tables: 1) Games 2) Teams. 
Teams has  columns 'team_name' and 'division'
Games has coloumns 'team_a', 'team_b', and 'division'

Sample Tables:

```
Teams table:

Team_name, Division
"team1","A"
"Team2","A"
"Team3","A"
"Team4","A"
"Team5","B"
"Team6","B"
"Team7","B"
"Team8","B"
```

For the games table, I want the division to come from the Teams table.. So when I insert Team1 Vs Team2 it auto fills the division as A.

```
Games Table:
Team_a, Team_b, Division
"Team1", "Team2", "A"
```

I'd like to create a trigger so that when a row is created in the games table it fills the division column with 'division' from the 'Teams' table where team_name = team_a.

Ideally I'll build it so it ensures division is the same for both team_a and team_b, but I figure small steps are best here.

After some debugging, I believe my error is in the:
    select division into @div_a from encex_autoschedTeams where team_name = new.team_a;

for some reason, the where clause is returning null. After some command line testing, it shouldn't be. Maybe New.team_a isn't right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code works perfectly. The problem was due to to parsing a string earlier on in the code and leaving a difficult to see space in the string of team_names. The query was returning null because it wasn't matching "team1" to " team1".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not use a trigger for this problem first go for a simple stored proc to store the data in games and respective records in teams. It would be pretty good. moreover the performance will also be reduced when you use a trigger because it runs every time when you insert a record, and you need to go for dedicated hosting servers to create triggers on your DB if you giving your website to a hosting site.

Here the reason for the error is you kept division column as **NOT NULL** and the query/trigger result can't  fetch the value for that division column. So it is raising error

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you explain what you mean by a simple stored proc? I am new to MYSQL.  Also, I do have the division coloum as NOT NULL, but I don't understand why it can't fetch the value for the division column. Am I using the where clause wrong?

Comment: I tried updating "set new.division = @div_a;" to "update gamestable set division=@div_a". I get the exact same error. Did I missunderstand?

Comment: make it AFTER INSERT instead of BEFORE INSERT

Comment: Ah yes! I should have noticed that. The problem now is that it can't update the table that calls the trigger. Error: Can't update table 'encex_autoschedGames' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: hey dna girl it seems you are not so good in DB concepts. you can not operate/ update the same table on which you created a trigger. Here you inserting a new record into encex_autoschedGames and calling a trigger and trying to update the same table...understand..It is purely illogical

Comment: i thought that the games table and the trigger calling table was different. let me know onething what would be your expected record set that need to be inserted into the teams table(let me know what team_a column contains what team_b contains and what division contains)